# How to pass the results of one SQL query to another query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to retrieve a table with the values of Cramer's correlation coefficients on a set of fields using the following SQL query:

```sql
WITH var_pairs AS (
        WITH vars AS (SELECT n FROM unnest(ARRAY['Performance Score', 'state', 'sex', 'maritaldesc', 'citizendesc', 'Hispanic/Latino', 'racedesc', 'Reason For Term', 'Employment Status', 'department', 'position', 'Manager Name', 'Employee Source']) AS n)
        SELECT vars1.n AS var1, vars2.n AS var2
        FROM vars AS vars1 CROSS JOIN vars AS vars2
    )
    SELECT
        (WITH
            -- Contingency table
            observed AS (
                SELECT 
                    var1 AS x, 
                    var2 AS y, 
                    COUNT(*) AS observed
                FROM hr_dataset
                GROUP BY var1, var2
            ),
            -- Sum of the rows of the contingency table
            row_total AS (
                SELECT 
                    x,
                    SUM(observed) AS row_total
                FROM observed
                GROUP BY x
            ),
            -- Sum of columns of the contiguity table
            col_total AS (
                SELECT
                    y,
                    SUM(observed) AS col_total
                FROM observed
                GROUP BY y
            ),
            -- Total number of observations
            grand_total AS (
                SELECT SUM(observed) AS grand_total
                FROM observed
            ),
            -- Expected frequencies
            expected AS (
                SELECT
                    observed.x,
                    observed.y,
                    (row_total.row_total * col_total.col_total) / grand_total.grand_total AS expected
                FROM
                    observed
                    INNER JOIN row_total USING(x)
                    INNER JOIN col_total USING(y)
                    CROSS JOIN grand_total
            ),
            -- Chi-square statistics
            chi_sq AS (
                SELECT
                    SUM(POWER(observed.observed - expected.expected, 2) / expected.expected) AS chi_sq
                FROM
                    observed 
                    INNER JOIN expected USING(x, y)
            ),
            count_x AS (
                SELECT 
                    count(DISTINCT x) AS count_x
                FROM
                    observed
            ),
            count_y AS (
                SELECT 
                    count(DISTINCT y) AS count_y
                FROM
                    observed
            )
        -- Cramer's correlation coefficient
        SELECT 
            SQRT(chi_sq / (grand_total * (least(count_x, count_y) - 1))) AS "Cramer\'s V"
        FROM 
            chi_sq
            CROSS JOIN grand_total
            CROSS JOIN count_x
            CROSS JOIN count_y
    )
    FROM var_pairs
```

Response from the server: ERROR: division by zero. As far as I understand, I am passing parameters var1 and var2 to the subquery incorrectly. How to do it correctly? I am using Postgres.

Comment: As the error states, you’re dividing by zero. So you need to check the three places where you are doing division. As no-one else has access to your data, only you can do this. Just start with the first SQL statement, run it and then keep adding the other statements until you find the error

Comment: Replace each expression for the denominator with `NULLIF(expression, 0)`. This will prevent division-by-zero exceptions and return `NULL` for each pair that lacks the needed observations. Although unrelated to the division-by-zero issue, consider refactoring the query to eliminate all but the first `WITH`, rename subqueries so they don't have the same names as their columns (e.g., change `observed` to `observations`, and combine aggregations from the same table (i.e., `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x) AS count_x, COUNT(DISTINCT y) AS count_y FROM observations` instead of separate subqueies).

Comment: Where does `hr_dataset` come from? I suppose that should be `var_pairs` instead? I do not get division by zero after replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a division by zero error, which means that you at some point try to perform this pattern

```
a / b
```

where `b` is 0. In mathematics division by zero is a special problem.

Let's suppose that you divide a / 0 and let's suppose its result is r:

a / 0 = r

Now, let's multiply the equation with 0, so we get:

a = 0 * r

so, for which r is it true that a = 0 * r? The answer is that it's true for any r, as long as a is 0. But it's false for any r as long as a is not 0.

Therefore:

```
a / 0
```

makes no sense if a <> 0 and a / 0 could be anything if a = 0.

So, division by zero is a special case in mathematics and programming languages handle this issue.

Since your denominator do not depend on the values of `var1` or `var2`, the problem we discuss is completely independent on how you pass them and the problem is that you divide by zero. To solve your problem you will need to make sure you do not divide by zero, so you check whether the denominator is zero, put a default in there if so and do the division otherwise. Something like:

```
case
    when denominator = 0 then 100
    else numerator / denominator
end
```